# Indicator functions in double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's suppose to have $x \in [a,b]$, $y \in [a,b]$ and $z \in [a,b]$. The double integral I need to compute is:

$\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) 1_{(x \leq z \leq y)} d_x d_y$

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the double integral as such or akin to:

$\int_x^y \int_x^y (x+y) 1_{(x \leq z \leq y)} d_x d_y$

Or if I can bring the Indicator function outside of it:

$[\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) d_x d_y]* 1_{(x \leq z \leq y)}$

What I'm struggling in is how to handle that $1_{(x \leq z \leq y)}$. If I'd had something like:

$\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) d_x d_y$ then the answer would be:

$[\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}]^b_a + c$

Therefore I do not undestand the asnwer changes when having that Indicator function or doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron My bad, I changed it to the correct values

Comment: If it is an integral $dx$, then do not "bring outside" of it anything involving $x$.  Same for $y$.  Does your notation $d_x$ mean something other than $dx$?

Comment: @GEdgar No it doesn't, thanks.

Comment: $[\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}]^b_a + c$ makes no sense. Do we replace the $x$ with $b$, then $a$ (then subtract), or do we replace the $y$, or do we replace both? Also the $c$ seems to come from nowhere; there is no "constant of integration" in the value of a definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

Your expressions with $x$ or $y$ being the limits of the integral and at the same time the integration variable do not have a meaning. In an integral $∫_a^b f(x) dx$, the $x$ exists only within the integral.

So about your indicator integral
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) 1_{\{x \leq z \leq y\}} dx dy
&= \int_a^b \int_a^z (x+y) 1_{\{x \leq z \leq y\}} dx dy & \text{since for } x > z \text{ the integrand is 0} \\
&= \int_a^b 1_{\{z \leq y\}} \int_a^z (x+y) dx dy  & \text{ since } 1_{\{x \leq z \leq y\}} = 1_{\{z \leq y\}} \text{ for } a \leq x \leq z,\\
& \text{ so it's a constant independent} & \text{of the integrand} \\
&= ∫_z^b ∫_a^z x+y d x dy & \text{ same for } y \\
&= ∫_z^b (z-a)y + ∫_a^z x dx dy & y \text{ independent of x} \\
&= ∫_z^b (z-a)y dy + (b - z) ∫_a^z x dx & \text{ second integral ind. of } y \\
&= (z-a) \frac{b^2 - z^2}2 + (b-z) \frac{z^2-a^2}2 & \text{ integral of linear fct.} \\
&= \frac12(z-a)(b-z)(b+z + z+a)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: pay attention! I made a mistake when integrating. See the fix now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess $z$ is a given number in $[a,b]$.  I would do this
$$
\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) 1_{(x \leq z \leq y)} dx dy
= \int_z^b \left(\int_a^z (x+y) dx\right) dy
$$
This result does not depend on $x$ and $y$.

---

Note
$$
\int_x^y \int_x^y (x+y) 1_{(x \leq z \leq y)} dx dy
$$
is a confusing (and hence bad) thing to write.  In general, do not use the same symbol for the dummy variable in an integral, and also for the bounds of integration.

---

Also,
$$
\int_a^b \int_a^b (x+y) dx dy
= [\frac{xy(x+y)}{2}]^b_a + c
$$
is incorrect.  Its computation is:
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left(\int_a^b (x+y) dx\right) dy
&=
\int_a^b\left(\frac{b^2}{2}+by - \frac{a^2}{2} -ay\right)\;dy
\\ &=
\frac{b^2}{2}(b-a) + b\frac{b^2-a^2}{2} 
- \frac{a^2}{2}(b-a)-a\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}
\\ &=a^3 - a^2b-b^2a+b^3
\end{align}